# Drying milled lumber

Tags: wood, lumber, diy-vs-pro

I want to mill my own lumber from a forested property and mill I have access to. I understand there is a long drying process involved, and I intend to dry a large volume.

What is the process for drying the lumber? How do I determine the drying times for various cuts?

I have access to a large garage as well to keep it out of the elements, of course.

Comment: Sounds like a question for our sister site, forestry.stackexchange.com!

Comment: There are a plethora of web sites that are all about home sawing of logs into lumber and timbers. Put fingers to keyboard and you can learn all about the the proper stacking, spacing and conditions for drying the cut wood.

Comment: Rule of thumb for air-drying is a year per inch of thickness, with adequate air circulation. Kiln or solar-kiln drying is faster but (even) more prone to checking if the end grain isn't sealed first. Wood will warp, so mill oversized and re-mill to final dimensions once dry.

Comment: I agree with 1 year per inch on hard woods, Soft wood is quite often shipped within a few days of being cut, occasionally the same day unless it is KD (kiln dried). +